# R replace numbers in a data frame based on their value

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with numbers like :

28521   59385   58381

V7220   25050   V7231

I need to replace them based on conditions like: 
if the number is bigger than 59380 and smaller than 59390 then code it as 1
delete numbers starts with "v"

so the frame work will be look like

28521   1      1

NA      25050  NA

How can I do this quickly for a huge data frame?

Comment: What have you tried? `as.numeric(df$column)` will work for replacing things that can't be converted to numbers with `NA`. For replacing, several of the "Related Questions" in the sidebar show the answer, e.g., [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065842/r-replace-value-according-to-its-current-value-in-data-frame?rq=1).

Comment: It would help if you provided a reproducible example in your question.  That way we would be able to create a data.frame of similar size to yours, try out a few things, and then report back with specifics of how long it took.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function then apply it to the columns of the matrix/data.frame after you convert to numeric to get rid of those V entries.

```
sapply(df,as.numeric)
# If you have factor instead of character
sapply(df,function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

replace <- function(x) {
x[x >= 59380 & x <= 59390] <- 1
return(x)
}
```

Comment: I tried sapply (df,as.numeric) it changed the value of the numbers
eg. 28521 59390 58540 became 
27 111 108
why did this happen

Comment: Because you had them as a `factor` instead of a `character`. `as.numeric` to a factor changes the factor to the factor level number.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c(28521, 59385, 58381, 'V7220', 25050, 'V7231')

as.numeric(ifelse(as.numeric(x) > 59380 & as.numeric(x) < 59390, 1, x))
```

This will return a warning message about `NA` values, but if you wrap it with `suppressWarnings`, you'll get what you want.

```
> suppressWarnings(as.numeric(ifelse(as.numeric(x) > 59380 & as.numeric(x) < 59390, 1, x)))
[1]  28521     1 58381    NA 25050    NA
```